# Why does multiprocessing not get response for API in correct time?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fastapi, starlette

I have an API setup written in FastAPI and I am hitting 1 endpoint using multiprocessing via 5 processes. Here is the reproducible setup:

#### API SETUP (please note this is NOT AN ASYNC API -> nothing is being awaited)

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
import PIL.Image as Image
import requests
from loguru import logger
import sys

log_format = "{level} {process}-{thread} {time} {name}:{line} - {message}"
logger.remove()
logger.add(sys.stderr, format=log_format, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)
logger.add("logs/" + "t_{time}.log", format=log_format, colorize=True, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

def get_the_image_from_net():
    a = requests.get("https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x5400x2700.png", verify=False)
    return True


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/expectoPatronum")
async def get_image_of_the_new_world():
    """
    Gets Image of the World
    """
    logger.info("Received request for getting Image of the world")
    image_bytes: bytes = get_the_image_from_net()
    logger.info("Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array")
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("image_downloader_api:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=10009)
```

#### How I am hitting this API using multiprocessing:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process
import requests
from loguru import logger
import sys 

log_format = "{level} {process}-{thread} {time} {name}:{line} - {message}"
logger.remove()
logger.add(sys.stderr, format=log_format, backtrace=True, diagnose=True, enqueue=True)
logger.add("logs/" + "t_{time}.log", format=log_format, colorize=True, backtrace=True, diagnose=True, enqueue=True)

manager = Manager()
process_dictionary = manager.dict()
process_completion_race_list = manager.list()

def test_function(index_iterator: int):
    logger.info(f"STARTING REQUEST FOR {index_iterator}")
    response = requests.get("http://localhost:10009/expectoPatronum")
    logger.info(f"ENDING REQUEST FOR {index_iterator}")


p1 = Process(target=test_function, args=(1,))
p2 = Process(target=test_function, args=(2,))
p3 = Process(target=test_function, args=(3,))
p4 = Process(target=test_function, args=(4,))
p5 = Process(target=test_function, args=(5,))

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()
p5.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
p4.join()
p5.join()
```

#### I have also tried hitting my API with a multiprocessing POOL

```py
pool = Pool(5)
pool.map(test_function, [i for i in range(1,6)])
pool.close()
```

However, in all cases the problem is the same:

Expectation: Since it is a SYNC API, the first request should be handled by API, return its response, then move on to handling 2nd request, return its response, and so on. Basically, everything should happen sequentially.

Observation and Problem: Only the first request's response takes some `x` amount of time to return a response, all other requests return responses at the same time:

##### LOGS from HITTING API script

```py
INFO 13607-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:23:16.958178+0530 __main__:20 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 1
INFO 13608-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:23:16.962500+0530 __main__:20 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 2
INFO 13609-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:23:16.966071+0530 __main__:20 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 3
INFO 13613-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:23:16.966112+0530 __main__:20 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 5
INFO 13611-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:23:16.966230+0530 __main__:20 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 4
INFO 13607-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:23:31.631877+0530 __main__:26 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 1
INFO 13613-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:24:24.807898+0530 __main__:26 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 5
INFO 13608-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:24:24.807911+0530 __main__:26 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 2
INFO 13611-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:24:24.808056+0530 __main__:26 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 4
INFO 13609-140018755471168 2022-07-13T10:24:24.808055+0530 __main__:26 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 3
```

As you can see `ENDING REQUEST FOR 1` is logged at `10:23:31` which is normal, as 1 request takes about 7-10 seconds. However, all other responses are returned at roughly the same time of `10:24:24`. How is this even possible? Ideally, each subsequent request should have taken 7-10 seconds more.

##### LOGS from API:

```py
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:23:16.966509+0530 image_downloader_api:28 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:23:31.630237+0530 image_downloader_api:30 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:23:31.631287+0530 image_downloader_api:28 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:23:53.571931+0530 image_downloader_api:30 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:23:53.572622+0530 image_downloader_api:28 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:24:05.753152+0530 image_downloader_api:30 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:24:05.753887+0530 image_downloader_api:28 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:24:15.155202+0530 image_downloader_api:30 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:24:15.155954+0530 image_downloader_api:28 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 12950-140191386634048 2022-07-13T10:24:24.806016+0530 image_downloader_api:30 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
```

These logs prove, that yes requests were being handled one-by-one and only the last request took time till `10:24:24`.

Comment: `get_the_image_from_net` might be synchronous, but you will have five async tasks (one from each process) that will call it.  "Synchronous" doesn't mean "serialized".  Because the call blocks, there's a nice opportunity for the other tasks to get started.

Comment: but `logs from api` prove, that other requests ended at 10:23:53, 10:24:05, 10:24:15, and 10:24:24. Why were all their responses captured at the Client-side at roughly 10:24:24 only?

Comment: Also `get_the_image_from_net` is definitely synchronous, and other tasks did not get started as we can see in `logs from api` that everything happened only after another. (which was also expected behaviour)

Comment: This does indeed look very strange.

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: I could not reproduce this on Windows, all requests happened serially like you would expect them to

Comment: Did you try the same code? and the Logs show different response times? (also, my OS is: WSL based out of Windows 11) [what more specs do you need?]

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer since comment space is limited

Try running this code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process
import requests
from loguru import logger
import sys

log_format = "{level} {process}-{thread} {time} {name}:{line} - {message}"
logger.remove()
logger.add(sys.stderr, format=log_format, backtrace=True, diagnose=True, enqueue=True)
logger.add("logs/" + "t_{time}.log", format=log_format, colorize=True, backtrace=True, diagnose=True, enqueue=True)


def test_function(index_iterator: int):
    logger.info(f"STARTING REQUEST FOR {index_iterator}")
    response = requests.get("http://localhost:10009/expectoPatronum")
    logger.info(f"ENDING REQUEST FOR {index_iterator}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn", force=True)
    p1 = Process(target=test_function, args=(1,))
    p2 = Process(target=test_function, args=(2,))
    p3 = Process(target=test_function, args=(3,))
    p4 = Process(target=test_function, args=(4,))
    p5 = Process(target=test_function, args=(5,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    p5.join()
```

If this runs with the expected output, then you can be sure it's using the start method `fork` that's causing this. Additionally, I am not familiar with `loguru` and it might be possible that somehow the logs are messing up rather than the actual code. Try using a queue (or just generic print statements) to "log" instead, just to make sure it's not `loguru` that's causing this.

**My output**

```
INFO 92324-54540 2022-07-14T13:16:52.969779+0530 __mp_main__:15 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 1
INFO 98628-30892 2022-07-14T13:16:52.969779+0530 __mp_main__:15 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 3
INFO 95024-78576 2022-07-14T13:16:52.981287+0530 __mp_main__:15 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 2
INFO 38264-96180 2022-07-14T13:16:52.996923+0530 __mp_main__:15 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 4
INFO 93336-112648 2022-07-14T13:16:52.996923+0530 __mp_main__:15 - STARTING REQUEST FOR 5
INFO 98628-30892 2022-07-14T13:17:20.219388+0530 __mp_main__:17 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 3
INFO 92324-54540 2022-07-14T13:17:34.634835+0530 __mp_main__:17 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 1
INFO 95024-78576 2022-07-14T13:17:46.080381+0530 __mp_main__:17 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 2
INFO 38264-96180 2022-07-14T13:18:05.049615+0530 __mp_main__:17 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 4
INFO 93336-112648 2022-07-14T13:18:14.804244+0530 __mp_main__:17 - ENDING REQUEST FOR 5
```